When usinga VRF together with a network namespace, I cannot ping the network namespace if the address assigned to it is already assigned in the host
My host has a network interface with gateway with 192.168.1.1 as address; the local address of this interface is 192.168.1.5. It's ok, a common network setup.
I tried to set up a VRF (virtual routing and forwarding) with a network namespace with a veth pair:
# ip netns add foo
# ip link add veth1 type veth peer name peer1 netns foo
# ip link set veth1 up
# ip link add vrf1 type vrf table 11
# ip link set vrf1 up
# ip link set dev veth1 master vrf1
# ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev veth1
# ip netns exec foo ip link set peer1 up
# ip netns exec foo ip addr add 192.168.1.5/24 dev peer1
# ip netns exec foo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev peer1

I can ping the address 192.168.1.1 inside the VRF:
# ip vrf exec vrf1 ping -c 3 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2035ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.034/0.037/0.003 ms

But I can't ping the network namespace side and also inside it (fron netns to host)
# ip vrf exec vrf1 ping -c 3 192.168.1.5
PING 192.168.1.5 (192.168.1.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.5 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2055ms

# ip netns exec foo ping -c 3 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2036ms

What does this happen? The scheme above is supposed to work because the route 192.168.1.0/24 in the host side and inside the VRF are isolated. Is there a way to make my setup work?
Here is my iptables and nft ruleset policy:
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1726260:2052159495]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1252923:1648247159]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [458556:402963495]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [809992:358120633]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1268625:761093754]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.2.2/32 -m comment --comment RfFDO4PWO76tWt7ebeA46F7o -j MARK --set-xmark 0x9/0xffffffff
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1252914:1648245650]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [809973:358117656]
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1171:135881]
:INPUT ACCEPT [117:10366]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2206:770071]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2230:720870]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.2.2/32 -o enp5s0 -m comment --comment RfFDO4PWO76tWt7ebeA46F7o -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT


table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
# Warning: table ip mangle is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip mangle {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.2.2.2  counter packets 404549 bytes 62349628 meta mark set 0x9
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type nat hook input priority srcnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 10.2.2.2 oifname "enp5s0"  counter packets 1 bytes 82 masquerade
    }
}
# Warning: table ip6 nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip6 nat {
    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip6 saddr fc00::cafe oifname "enp5s0"  counter packets 0 bytes 0 # Warning: XT target MASQUERADE not found
xt target "MASQUERADE"
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }
}
# Warning: table ip6 mangle is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip6 mangle {
    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        ip6 saddr fc00::cafe  counter packets 0 bytes 0 meta mark set 0x9
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}


PS: I need the address of the network namespace to be in range 192.168.1.0/24.

Please add the output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset to your post.

@TomYan It's done. But looking at them, I think they are ok.
